# How to deal with covariance between factors in an RDA (is it a big problem)?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, covariance

I'm trying to figure out which factors are driving differences in my biotic matrix, among other things, relative abundance weighted mean community traits (similar to how Moillot et al 2013 [TREE] characterize their trait matrix). The issue I'm running in to is that because these traits are dependent on all dependent on the same value in each community, relative abundances, they tend to covary (Fig 1 below). Normally I'd cut factors and use one as a surrogate for the rest, but mechanistically I'd expect several of these to have different influences on the process of interest. When I run the redundancy analysis (RDA) I get a logical story in accordance with this expectation (Fig 2 below), but for the sake of rigor I'd rather check. Also, it has been a while now since my last refresher on multivariate statistics so I have a few questions.

**Question 1: how big of a problem is this with ordination analyses?**

**Question 2: is there a recommended way of dealing with this covariation problem?**

**Question 3: is there an alternative (to RDA) method and published reference that would be preferable?**

Any and all advice is appreciated!

**Note:** these are super rough figures for example purposes and should not be reproduced beyond this question

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by RDA?

Comment: Sorry about that @Michael Chernick .  redundancy analysis